# Too many javax Params

Tags: java, rest, arguments

We have APIs that have number of @DefaultValue and @QueryParam running into double digits. Is there any elegant way of reducing the cutter on the argument list? Can we separately specify the mapping elsewhere and inject a single elegant object?

```
public Response doRestfulAPI(@QueryParam("param1") String param1,
                             @QueryParam("param2") String param2,
                             @QueryParam("param3") String param3,
                             .......
                             @QueryParam("paramN") String paramN)
```

The above, we like to make it more elegant like:

```
public Response doRestfulAPI(@QueryParam("complex") Complex complexParams)
```

Is something like the above possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using JAX-RS. In this case you should hava a look at [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html):

```
 public class MyBean {
   @QueryParam("param1")
   private String param1;

   @QueryParam("param2")
   private String param2;

   ...
 }
```

In your resource class:

```
 public Response doRestfulAPI(@BeanParam MyBean bean) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Cool approach! Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

@micha's solution is good but you can also use a MultivaluedMap for uriInfo which is less elegant but more dynamic.

```
public Response doRestfulAPI(@Context UriInfo info)
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = info.getQueryParameters();
    String param1 = params.getFirst("param1");
    String param2 = params.getFirst("param2");
    String param3 = params.getFirst("param3");
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Thats a very cool solution, however the problem here is, it removes the information regarding what the API really takes in as params. But still an elegant solution! No doubt!

Answer (score 0):

You can receive arguments list:

```
@GET
@Path("/info")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getInfoByIds(@QueryParam("id") List<String> ids){}
```

Query would be like

```
/info?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

Please note that URL may be limited to ~2000 characters.